# Julia: is a function that receives a Dict as input and output a Dict type stable?

Tags: julia

I am trying to port some Matlab code to Julia to see if optimized Julia code can run faster than optimized Matlab code. The Matlab code is a single function describe a model with multiple components. In Matlab, the function receives a structure that contains many parameters and configurations of the model as input, and output a structure that stores the behavior of all components.

I am quite new to Julia, but I know that Julia functions need to be type stable to be fast. My question is if I write the Julia function that receive a Dict (which is similar to Matlab's structure) as input, and output a Dict, is the function still type stable?

In Matlab code, the structure contains different types of variables including matrices, character arrays, and function handles.

Comment: Why not make it a struct? Or a tuple? Or a NamedTuple?

Comment: To expand upon the comment from @ChrisRackauckas, Julia does have structures (also called _composite types_), and that's probably what you should be using here.  See the [Julia docs on types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I do need to read more on Julia docs.

Comment: @CameronBieganek Is it possible to make an array of the same composite types?

Comment: Yep, that's quite common. You can make them explicitly like `[MyInt(1), MyInt(2)]`, or you can use [array comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Comprehensions-1), or you can use the dot syntax for broadcasting, like `MyInt.([1, 2])`. The [StructArrays.jl](https://github.com/piever/StructArrays.jl) package could also be handy.

Answer (score 2):

A Dict{String,Any} should, because its values will be "boxed" by Julia, be technically slower than a fully typed structure. However, your function is going to spend most of its time calculating and only will put the results in the boxed Dict values at the end of its run.

To be sure that the function internals are stable, type hints with the input Dict may be needed, e.g.:

```
function f(d::Dict)
    width::Float64 = d["width"]  # now we work with width, not d["width"]
```

As long as such internals of the function themselves are kept type stable, using such a Dict, or even a Dict{Any,Any}, just to input and output several values should not affect total timing enough to prevent the Julia function from running faster than another (MATLAB) implementation, as long as it is indeed a faster function otherwise.

Comment: So if the function will be called by a large number of times (in my case, I need to perform a genetic algorithm to optimize parameters), and the input and output Dict (or struct, as some comments suggest) contains different types of variables, will it affect the performance?

Comment: For a short function with multiple calls such as from an inner loop, it is definitely best to pass a fully typed structure. Julia passes these by reference (especially if they are a mutable struct), so there is no copying or hashing overhead.   For a large function that will be called seldom, the type of calling parameters used should not affect performance, especially if the time consuming calculations in the function are done with local variables that are more easily kept type stable.